# Set specific tag names for various ec2 instances while using count parameter

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**Objective:** Assign specific tags to `aws_instance` resource while using count parameter.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami           = "ami-09ba48996007c8b50"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  count         = 3
  tags = {
    "Name" = "ansible.${count.index}"
  }
}
```

This code creates 3 instances with tags `ansible.0`, `ansible.1` and `ansible.2`

Is there a way to name the first instance tag

```
"Name" = "ansible-master"
```

and the other two instances as

```
"Name" = "ansible-node"
```

Comment: `ansible-master` and `ansible-node` are distinctly different types of systems, so I would consider splitting them into two different resources.

Answer (score 0):

Condition in based on the value of `count`.

If count is `0`, then it will set the Name as `ansible-master`
Otherwise, it will set the Name as `ansible-node`

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami           = "ami-09ba48996007c8b50"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  count         = 3
  tags = {
    "Name" = count.index == 0 ? "ansible-master" : "ansible-node"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham. The conditional expression works!

Comment: @moonpie If it solves your query, please mark the answer as expected to close the query and upvote the answer xD.